# What kind of search algorithm do I need for this inconsistent grid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, math

I am developing a small tool for my game that will allow myself and friends to click on the map-layout and create waypoints and then find the closest way to find them. This is how it looks when the search is complete https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ6Sd.png

the red line shows how it ***should*** search to the goal, now it will just follow all green nodes

All the white dots is "non related" to each other and has small distance differences between each and other and will always be different.

The green dots are pre-white dots which were "walked to"

The red dot is the closest node to my goal.

**This is how i do it today:**

1. Loop through nodes and add a "Weight" then push the new array to "Node-stack"

   > for(i=0; i <...etc....){
   >
   > **newNode**[0] = Weight
   >
   > **newNode**[1] = OriginalIdFromCoordinates
   >
   > **Node-stack**.push(newNode)
   >
   > }

*The weight is basically Manhattan distance from "Start" to "Finish" plus the distance from Start to **Node[i]***

2. A) Get the "cheapest" node from my **"Node-stack"** and push it into a **"Cheap-stack"** then remove the original **"Nodes"** entry stack

> **TmpWeight** = Infinity;
>
> **TmpI**; 
>   for(i=0; i< **Node-stack**.length; i++){
>
> if(**Node-stack**[0] < **TmpWeight**){ //Node-stack[0] = NewNode[0] etc
>
> **TmpI** = **Node-Stack**[0];
>
> **TmpWeight** = **Node-stack**[1];
>
> }
>
> **Cheap-stack**.push(TmpI + TmpWeight)
>
> **Node-stack.remove(TmpI)**
>
> }

**Repeat step 1 with Adding weights but now the "Startcoord" is the last coord used for Cheap-stack** and do all this till the Node-stack is empty

For the return i just go through the list and stop when im close to the node.

So i know this could be a pretty ineffective way... So thats why im seeking guidance too how my approach this problem better?

All the other search algorithm-guides only use a perfect square grid with exact distances, so i could not find anything that suited my problem

Comment: I've understood nothing. Red dot is the goal, but where is the start point?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)